# Grails and default mysql encoding

Tags: mysql, grails, encoding

I want to configure my Grails application running with MYSQL to set the database and its table to `utf-8`. How can I achieve that?

Here is my `DataSource.groovy`:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = 'login'
            password = 'password'
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"            
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = 'login'
            password = 'password'
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8'
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            properties {
                validationQuery="select 1"
                testWhileIdle=true
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=900000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But grails always create database and table with `latin1`

How can I make the Grails app to create `utf-8` encoded databases and tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

If still getting error then create database as

```
CREATE DATABASE database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Already test, I just pass the `useUnicode=true` to `useUnicode=yes` before posting here.
Seem to be the only difference beetwen you and me. Does removing `autoReconnect=true` change anything ?

Comment: In one of my project we create database ad `CREATE DATABASE database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` for mysql console and having `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"` in DataSource and it is working. Have a try with localhost as well.

Comment: The way you create your database is ok. So this must be done at the creation of the DB, thanks !